# Jake Wharton's ViewPagerIndicator NullPointerException on findViewById(R.id.indicator)

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I am trying to implement Jake Wharton's ViewPagerIndicator into my already working, fully functional, application with a PagerTabStrip. I followed the instructions on the git repo and removed my calls to PagerTabStrip.

I added the library into my workspace and added it to my app as a library.
My main_activity code looks like this:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_page_view);

ViewPager vpPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vpPager);
adapterViewPager = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
vpPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);

TabPageIndicator mIndicator = (TabPageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
mIndicator.setViewPager(vpPager);
```

I get a RunTimeException, NullPointerException when my code reaches mIndicator.setViewPager(vpPager); This is because mIndicator is null. Which I assume means findViewById is not working but my resource xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vpPager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>
```

Everything seems to be right but I am not sure why this is not working.

My logcat shows this:

```
03-19 00:10:15.201: E/AndroidRuntime(1486): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-19 00:10:15.201: E/AndroidRuntime(1486): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start     activity ComponentInfo{com./////.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-19 00:10:15.201: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
03-19 00:10:15.201: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at  android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
03-19 00:10:15.201: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-19 00:10:15.201: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
03-19 00:10:15.201: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-19 00:10:15.201: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-19 00:10:15.201: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-19 00:10:15.201: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-19 00:10:15.201: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-19 00:10:15.201: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-19 00:10:15.201: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-19 00:10:15.201: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-19 00:10:15.201: E/AndroidRuntime(1486): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-19 00:10:15.201: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at com.////.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47)
03-19 00:10:15.201: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
03-19 00:10:15.201: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-19 00:10:15.201: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
03-19 00:10:15.201: E/AndroidRuntime(1486):     ... 11 more
```

Thank you and I hope someone can help!

NOTE: In the log I replaced my com information with //// so this is not a mistake in the log.

Comment: Do you call super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); before setContentView(R.layout.activity_page_view) ?

Comment: Yes I did. Forgot to put that in my question.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything apparently wrong with the code you posted. So, are you certain the layout you're inflating is the one that contains the `TabPageIndicator` and have you tried simply cleaning and refreshing your project?

Comment: @adneal I am sure that the layout contains the xml I posted above. I have also tried cleaning and refreshing my project many times. I also went ahead and tried to use a different tab project called PagerSlidingTabStrip by astuetz but the same exact problem occurs.

Comment: @RoyValentine [Try using Google's official tab bar.](https://plus.google.com/108967384991768947849/posts/X8fg63wK6S8) It's only two classes, copy them into your project (no libraries).

Comment: @adneal I added the two files to my project and chnaged my code to use the SlidingTabLayout. However, I still get similar results: Exception Details java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.//.//.view.SlidingTabLayout$MyObserver
The main difference between their code and mine is that I am instantiating everything in onCreate for class that extends FragmentActivity. Where they start a fragment and instantiate in onViewCreated. So they call view.findViewById() where I just call findViewById

Comment: @RoyValentine What is "MyObserver", that isn't a part of Google's example?

Comment: @adneal I was trying a version someone edited but I went back to using Google's example and I still come accross a ClassNotFoundException for  the SlidingTabLayout and a NullPointer at my findViewById. My implementation is still the same as described in my last comment.

Comment: @RoyValentine Would you join this chat so we can discuss this in real time, please? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50214/22494426